# Can I insert HTML into a page via a file, and then interact with those DOM elements with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome Extension.

- The extension injects some CSS and JavaScript when .html files on the users local drive are loaded in the browser (file:///).
- My extension adds an extensive UI to the page that allows the user to modify and manipulate the original source code from their .html file.
- The primary purpose of the extension is debugging and QAing HTML email newsletters. Here's just a few things that it does:

  - Checking links for the appropriate parameters.
  - Toggling images off and on to simulate popular email clients.
  - Displaying the source code side-by-side to show a desktop view and multiple mobile sized views.
  - A function that takes the original HTML and generates a plain text version.
  - A function that toggles `<style>` blocks off and on to simulate popular email clients ignoring them.
  - Email files are backed up via Dropbox and the Dropbox API is integrated to allow for quick sharing right from the email newsletter.

Until now I've been using javascript in my injected content script like this to create all of my menu items.

```
var debugOrb = document.createElement("div");
debugOrb.id = "borders-orb";
debugOrb.className = "borders-orb orb glyph";
debugOrb.addEventListener("click", toggleBorders, false);
orbsBottom.appendChild(debugOrb);
```

Here's an extended view of the code I've written to create all of these toggles/menu items: http://pastebin.com/LQTkNhpP

My problem is that now I'm going to be adding a LOT more clickable menu items like this. And it feels like if I do, it's going to get out of hand really quick. Especially since I'll be nesting a lot of `div`s to make the whole thing look organized and using JavaScript to create lots of text nodes too.

My first thought was what if I could just create my entire menu in regular HTML, then just inject that file into the page with the javascript in my content script. I'm barely intermediate level with JavaScript though. And as I understand it, if I did this, I'd lose my ability to use `onclick` handlers for all of these `div`s I'm creating.

Is there an efficient way to handle my goal that I'm not aware of?

Notes:

- I'm not using any framework/plugins like React, Angular, or jQuery.

Comment: I've had similar issues before, I would load up a page using XHR instead of doing a standard HTTP request. I am not very well endowed on Prototype but on jQuery you'd use a `on` function, so for example, if your container's ID is `clickable` on your appended file, then you could do something like: `$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function(){ // things }` and it would work even if it is an appended element. Another thing would be embedding the script on the appended page itself.

Comment: You can attach just one click handler for the entire container and check event.target inside.

Comment: Could you post a couple more examples of the menu items you are creating?

Comment: @ProfessorAllman It's a lot of repetition, I'm not sure what showing more would help with? They all look just like the one I posted. Just imagine that 40-50 times. Different class names, ids, and function names. And then they'd all be wrapped in more `div`s for presentation. Probably a bunch of text nodes as well.

Comment: @jkupczak It'll help to see if your design could be modified, and maybe if this is a [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/242485) problem. Could you post maybe 2 more blocks and the corresponding click handler functions.

Comment: @ProfessorAllman Here's a pastebin with a bunch of my code. Certainly not all of it! Let me know if more is required and I'll put something together. I've also updated my question to provide more context as to what my extension's goal is. http://www.pastebin.com/LQTkNhpP

Comment: There are multiple ways to add a bunch of HTML. There's a crossover point where it's more efficient to use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` with an HTML string; with even more HTML, an external file. Even building the elements with `createElement()`, assuming adding a bunch of elements, you should have functions that do most of the element construction. For example, the 5 lines of code you have should be a single line, something like: `orbsBottom.appendChild(newElementWithClick('div','borders-orb','borders-orb orb glyph',toggleBorders)`. You can add `var debugOrb =` if doing something more with it.

Answer (score 0):

Once the html is added you can always get the element by id and then add an event listener to that element. You can have functions relate to the divs and then onload create the event listeners. `element.addEventListener ('click', function);`